# Why won't my amChart serial chart render if the config includes the categoryAxis property?

Tags: amcharts

I have a chart that refuses to render properly if I include the `categoryAxis` property in the chart options. By "render properly", I mean that the plot area shows up, the title is displayed, but none of the columns are rendered.

[image]

I am using an AmCharts serial chart with [GrantMStevens amChartsDirective](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular) because my project is built in Angularjs.

[Here is a plunk with the `categoryAxis` commented out.](http://plnkr.co/edit/nTAa3jBX4IO7jOkZ62ax?p=preview) If you enable that line of code, the chart will immediately exhibit this behavior.

This chart uses text values for the `categoryField` and numeric vlaues for the `valueField`. I have another chart that uses date values for the `categoryField` and numeric values for the `valueField` and it works just fine.

I am assuming that there some interaction between the fact that this a not a `categoryField` is not a date value that causes this but I cannot find any combination of properties that lets me set properties on the `categoryField`.

This is what I WANT to do:

```
    categoryAxis: {
        gridAlpha: 0.3,
        gridColor: "GRAY"
    },
```

**Does anyone know why this doesn't work?**

Here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="amChartsDirectiveExample">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div ng-controller="amChartsController2" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;">
        <am-chart id="mySecondChart" options="amChartOptions2"></am-chart>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/themes/chalk.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/themes/black.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.0/themes/dark.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ThumbsAlmighty/amCharts-Angular/master/dist/amChartsDirective.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="theme.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
angular.module('amChartsDirectiveExample', ['amChartsDirective'])
.controller('amChartsController2', function($scope) {
    $scope.chartData = [
            {
                "EscalationCount": "2",
                "Area": "One"
            },
            {
                "EscalationCount": "9",
                "Area": "Two"
            },
            {
                "EscalationCount": "5",
                "Area": "Three"
            },
            {
                "EscalationCount": "4",
                "Area": "Four"
            },
            {
                "EscalationCount": "3",
                "Area": "Five"
            }];

    $scope.amChartOptions2 = {
    type: "serial",
    categoryField: "Area",
    startDuration: 1,
    rotate: true,
    theme: "light",
    trendLines: [],
    //categoryAxis: {},  // Uncomment this line to break the chart.
    graphs: [{
        balloonText: "[[title]] for [[category]]: [[value]]",
        fillAlphas: 1,
        id: "AmGraph-1",
        title: "Escalation Volume",
        type: "column",
        valueField: "EscalationCount"
    }],
    guides: [],
    valueAxes: [{
        id: "ValueAxis-1",
        title: "EscalationCount",
    }],
    allLabels: [],
    balloon: [],
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    titles: [{
        id: "Title-1",
        size: 15,
        text: "Lookit me! I rendered the Chart title!"
    }],
    data: $scope.chartData
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the angular directive sets `parseDates` to true by default if you have a categoryAxis defined, which breaks if your chart isn't date-based. If you set `parseDates: false` in your categoryAxis, it will work.

```
  categoryAxis: {
    parseDates: false,
    gridAlpha: 0.3,
    gridColor: "#d3d3d3"
  },
```

Here's your updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/TYZdR0KEOAKcbHnGdTfP?p=preview

Note, I changed your `gridColor` to the hex equivalent. While named colors will work, if you plan on using the export plugin, you'll need to set your colors as a hex string.

Comment: That did it! You are awesome! I will file a bug on this with amChartsDirective. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome! I also noticed that they're still referencing the ancient cdnjs versions of the library. You can link directly to AmCharts' hosted CDN files if you want the latest version. I updated my plunk to point to those files.